# Higher order function in scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

```
def map2(fun: Int=>Int)(a_list: List[Int]): List[Int] ={
   if (a_list.isEmpty){
     return List()
   } else{
     return fun(a_list.head)::map2 fun(a_list.tail)
   }
}
```

It keeps giving me this error:

```
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `map2 _` or `map2(_)(_)` instead of `map2`.
    return fun(a_list.head)::map2 fun(a_list.tail)
                             ^
```

Comment: Idiomatic Scala doesn't use `return`. You don't need it.

Comment: It would be more obvious if you included the first part of the error message where it explains the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot some parentheses

```
def map2(fun: Int=>Int)(a_list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
   if (a_list.isEmpty){
     List()
   } else {
     fun(a_list.head) :: map2(fun)(a_list.tail)
   }
}
```